# pandas difference between two rows with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having few hundred row with a columns item, number and value.
In value column I want to calculate difference of value between two rows which can be simply done with

```
df['value']=df['value'].diff(-1)
```

But in value column there are all numbers but at few places there is a string value "NO", so here I want to check while getting difference of current row value with previous value either or both value in row is "NO", then it should skip its check and move ahead.
For, eg while getting difference a value is "NO" than it should ignore it or place NAN in front of it.
Output looks like:

```
value output
5       NAN
4        1
6       -2
NO      NAN
7       NAN
NO      NAN
8       NAN
10      -2
NO      NAN
NO      NAN
10      NAN
11       1
```

As per above output "NAN" or an other string value will be okay.
Any help would be great thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what the input looks like for that output?

Comment: If the `NO` values are strings, then your numbers in that column won't be integers/numbers. You would have to convert the column to numeric (eg. `pd.to_numeric()`) and convert the 'NO' to NaN's.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have strings, or mixed types, use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`, then [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df['output'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce').diff()
```

*NB. for `int` add `.convert_dtypes()`*

output:

```
   value  output
0      5     NaN
1      4    -1.0
2      6     2.0
3     NO     NaN
4      7     NaN
5     NO     NaN
6      8     NaN
7     10     2.0
8     NO     NaN
9     NO     NaN
10    10     NaN
11    11     1.0
```

Comment: @utsav did it work as you want?